# Django: objects.raw() shows error while working with Postgresql but works fine while using sqlite3 database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, django-queryset

My code works fine when I use the **sqlite3 DB**. But when I use **Postgresql** my code throws error `column "product_variants.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 1: SELECT * FROM  product_variants  WHERE product_id=6 GROUP BY...`
I'm using AWS database, connected to my Postgresql.
*I have made all necessary migrations already.*

## views.py

```
def product_detail(request,id,slug):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=id)
    context = {'product': product,}
    if product.variant !="None": # Product have variants
        if request.method == 'POST': #if we select color
            variant_id = request.POST.get('variantid')
            variant = Variants.objects.get(id=variant_id) #selected product by click color radio
            colors = Variants.objects.filter(product_id=id,size_id=variant.size_id )
            sizes = Variants.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM  product_variants  WHERE product_id=%s GROUP BY size_id',[id])
            # sizes = Variants.objects.filter(product_id=id).values('size_id')
            print(sizes)
            query += variant.title+' Size:' +str(variant.size) +' Color:' +str(variant.color)
        else:
            variants = Variants.objects.filter(product_id=id)
            colors = Variants.objects.filter(product_id=id,size_id=variants[0].size_id )
            sizes = Variants.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM  product_variants  WHERE product_id=%s GROUP BY size_id',[id])
            # sizes = Variants.objects.filter(product_id=id).values('size_id')
            print(sizes)
            variant =Variants.objects.get(id=variants[0].id)
        context.update({'sizes': sizes, 'colors': colors,
                        'variant': variant,'query': query
                        })
    # print(product.countreview())
    return render(request,'eshop/products.html',context)
```

In the above code, I have tried to replace the .raw() query to .filter() (which I later commented out) but still, it doesn't work as I expected; it doesn't show the size details but shows the color details in the `products.html`.

## models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):

    VARIANTS = (
        ('None', 'None'),
        ('Size', 'Size'),
        ('Color', 'Color'),
        ('Size-Color', 'Size-Color'),

    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    variant = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=VARIANTS, default='None')

class Color(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def color_tag(self):
        if self.code is not None:
            return mark_safe('<p style="background-color:{}">Color </p>'.format(self.code))
        else:
            return ""


class Size(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Variants(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = models.ForeignKey(
        Color, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    size = models.ForeignKey(
        Size, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    image_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM  product_variants  WHERE product_id=%s GROUP BY size_id` is not valid. Although it is acceptable in SQLite, it returns an arbitrary row (usually the 1st row) for each `size_id`. So maybe you should rethink about what you want this query to return.

Comment: Can you help me out in fixing this? I tried a piece which I commented out. I didn't the expected results.

Comment: Obviously you want in the results 1 row for each `size_id`. But which row? There is no first, second or last in a table. You must explain what you want the query to return.

Comment: The 'product' has a 'size' variants associated with it. I want the query to fetch all the sizes associated with that product.id @forpas

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote

```
sizes = Variants.objects.raw('SELECT DISTINCT * FROM  product_variants WHERE product_id=%s ORDER BY size_id',[id])
```

and it seemed to work fine.